# how to focus google marker by marker title?

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to focus on marker by giving title right now i am focusing by using lat and lng

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89454, 75.82607), 15.0f));
```

So is there anyway i could focus on particular marker by Title name of the marker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store your markers in a `Map<String Marker>` using the title as the key:

```
private Map<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap<>();
```

When you add your markers to the map, you need to also add them to the hashmap:

```
String markerTitle = "My Marker";
LatLng markerPosition = new LatLng(26.89454, 75.82607);
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPosition).title(markerTitle));
markers.put(markerTitle, marker); // Add the marker to the hashmap using it's title as the key
```

Then you can center your marker querying the hashmap:

```
private void centerMarker(String title) {
    Marker marker = markers.get(title);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 15f));
}
```

Comment: and sir do u have anyway if i am fetching marker name , lat & lng from server then how can i do this same there ?

Comment: You can do it this way too, you only need to get the data from your server and set the location and title from there

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your code there so it's clearer?