# How to search marker by title on android google map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I'm retrieving markers from web service using json and I'd like to search them on the map using the marker property title

Here is java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fragment.getMap();
        //  googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        new RetrieveTask().execute();
    }

    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.43.229/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    String name;
    LatLng latLng;
    double lat;
    double lng;

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = result.get(i);
                lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
                name = hmPlace.get("name");
                String locality = hmPlace.get("locality");
                String city = hmPlace.get("city");
                latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.snippet(locality + "," + city);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.school_marker));
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(24.66372, 93.90627), 8.0f));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:hint="Search Here" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:onClick="onMapSearch"
            android:text="Search" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589140/how-to-focus-google-marker-by-marker-title/39589336#39589336

Comment: i couldn't find the answer